# Setting initial value for a new foreign key on django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following django models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
   something = models.ForeignKey('Something')
   extra_data = models.ForeignKey('ModelB')

class ModelB(models.Model):
   something = models.ForeignKey('Something')
```

I have registered both models with django admin.

Is is possible to pre-set ModelB's `something` to the parent's `something` value when I create a new Model B via the `+` button?

[image]

I have tried using `formfield_for_foreignkey` and setting `kwargs["initial"]` but that only is able to set the foreign key itself, it does not provide default values for new objects.

This should be possible to do by making the `+` link URL to add `&something=` to the current object's `something` value. But I am not sure how to tell django to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around it by adding custom JS in the admin webpage.

```
class ModelA_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = ModelA
    class Media:
        js = ('admin/js/mycustomscript.js',)
```

In mycustomscript.js:

- Add a document load event that:

  - Finds the `something` select html element using the xpath:

    `//div[contains(@class, 'field-something')]//select`
  - Uses select.value to retrieve the selected `something` pk
  - Then finds the `extra_data`'s `+` button using the xpath:

    `//div[contains(@class, 'field-extra_data')]//a[contains(@class, 'add-related')]`
  - Finally adds the field value via get params into the link:

    `` a.href += `&something=${selected}`; ``